# pass variables to shell script over ssh

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

How do I make $1 and $2 variables to the remote shell through ssh. Below is the sample,

```
#!/bin/bash
user_name="${1}"
shift
user_password="${1}"
shift
tenant_name="${1}"
realscript="/IDM_ARTIFACTS/reset.sh"
ssh -qT oracle@slc05pzz.us.oracle.com bash -c "'echo $user_name'" < "$realscript"
```

I am able to echo $user_name but not able to access it in $realscript. 
Cant call using HERE tags or single quotes'' as the script doesn't have straight forward commands.
What other options do I have? Please help

Comment: So you want to call the reset.sh script? Does it take any other input than cmd-line options?

Comment: Is `reset.sh` on the remote host?

Comment: @Jack yes reset.sh has to be on remote host

Comment: yeah @W.Mann want to call reset.sh. I just want to pass command line arguments to reset.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have your script, so I put a test one on my remote host:

```
$ realscript=/home/jack/show_params.sh

$ second="second one"

$ ssh TEST cat ${realscript}
#!/bin/bash
nParams=$#
echo There are ${nParams} parameters.
for (( ii=1; ii<=${nParams}; ii++ )); do
    echo "$1"
    shift
done

$ ssh TEST 'bash '${realscript}' "first one" '\'${second}\'
There are 2 parameters.
first one
second one
```

The quoting gets a bit weird, but you can pass into parameters variables with spaces.